# Exporting graphs in SVG format

Tags: html, svg, data-visualization, visualization, stata

Stata can [export graphs](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?graph_export) into various formats, including `eps`, `pdf`, `wmf` and `emf`.

To be `HTML5`-compliant, I would make `svg` graphs out of any of this, but results with online [conversion](https://cloudconvert.org/svg-to-wmf) [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035588/how-to-convert-wmf-files-to-svg-files) or Photoshop do not display well.

How can I produce `svg` output from within Stata?

A little **R** or Python script is alright, but the main workflow is tied to Stata.

Note that I am using a Mac, but colleagues also use Windows.

Comment: Once the graphs are created in some Stata format, you can shell out and convert them using ImageMagick from within Stata with `!convert graph.png graph.svg`. ImageMagick is available for Windows and Mac. There are probably other programs that you can use in this way.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I think InkScape is better suited for SVGs, but sure, I can try one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Stata (14+) support exporting graphs in scalable vector graphics format natively:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. twoway scatter price mpg

. graph export auto.svg
(file auto.svg written in SVG format)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform solution I have had good luck with exporting to `eps` format first and then using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.com) to convert to `svg`. You can do this on the command-line:

```
inkscape -f graph.eps --export-plain-svg=graph.svg
```

The `svg` files are sometimes, but not always, smaller than their `eps` counter-parts. If you find some files that Inkscape does not convert well, you can see more options for this part [here](https://superuser.com/questions/198460/converting-between-eps-and-svg-format).