# how to know if a metafile is monochromatic or have color?

Tags: c#, .emf

Is there any way to know if an EMF file is only black-white or has some color ?. You can check the color palette or otherwise ?. Someone who can help me with some code please? I need to know the percentage of colors of each file generated by a program, but only if it is not monochromatic, and do not want to make a pixel by pixel count of all files. Thank You

Comment: Did you try reading the spec? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250370.aspx

Comment: Can http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557852/30594 provide you more directions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, this is easy to do:

First, load the EMF file into a bitmap:

```
Image img = new Metafile(@"MyFile.emf");
var bmp = new Bitmap(img);
```

Then you can test if its color by using this function:

```
bool isColor = IsColor(bmp);

private bool IsColor(Bitmap bmp)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (!(c.R == c.B && c.R == c.G))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Basically its testing each pixel. If a file is grayscale or monochrome, then the RGB values of a given pixel would be set to the same value. If any of the pixels don't have equal RGB values, then it must be color.

Comment: "and do not want to make a pixel by pixel count of all files"